# How to access to value in ets?

Tags: ets

```
value = :ets.lookup(:table, key)
```

So, in example above, when I use ets.lookup i receive a list with map that's contains a key and values. But i want to get values only. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ets:lookup_element/3`. Doc: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#lookup_element-3

```
user = :ets.lookup_element(:users, hash, 2)
```